# App running on debug mode only for Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am not sure what is wrong with my Android Studio IDE, but whenever I run the app inside flutter it always runs on debug mode. Please see the label on the right side of the corner.

[image]

**Logs:**

Launching lib\main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode...

> Initializing gradle... Resolving dependencies... Running Gradle task
> 'assembleDebug'... Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
> Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... Syncing files to device
> POCO F1...

Comment: I think that's a normal behavior, if you need to run it on release mode use: `flutter run --release`

Answer (score 56):

Have you tried running your code in "release" mode?

Within a terminal you can do that via `flutter run --release`.

In Android Studio you could `double tap shift` to bring up the `search everywhere` command window. If you simply type `release` you should be able to find the `Flutter Run main.dart in Release Mode` command.

[image]

Also you can find this in the menu under "Run" just like so:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

- ##### Running commands:

  App by default runs on debug mode, it is bit janky but needed to provide features like hot reload and hot restart. However, if you want to run the app in other modes, try these commands:

  1. **Release mode:**

     ```
     flutter run --release
     ```
  2. **Profile mode:**

     ```
     flutter run --profile
     ```

---

- ##### Adding flags in the IDE:

  You can also add these flags in IDE, click on `main.dart` in the toolbar:

  [image]

  Add `--release` flag in the `Additional run flags` option

  [image]

Answer (score 15):

From Run→Edit Configurations, you can create two configurations (copy and paste the first, then rename)  ***add additional’s arguments*** as `--debug` for debug an `--release` for release and chose one of those to start your app in Debug mode or Release mode (Let gradle to build for you :) ).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you build your apps in vsCode.
Then, open your terminal(`CTRL` + `) and type a command.

```
flutter run --release
```

Answer (score 5):

#### To remove the flutter debug banner, there are several possibilities :

**1- The first one** is to use the *debugShowCheckModeBanner* property in your **[MaterialApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXZpm.png)** widget .

**Code :**

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

And then do a **hot reload**.

**2-The second possibility** is to *hide debug mode banner* in **Flutter Inspector** if you use **Android Studio** or **IntelliJ IDEA** .

[image]

**3- The third possibility** is to use [Dart DevTools](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-24/) .

---

#### But if you want to switch to release mode ,

Use this command for running your app `flutter run --release`

or
In Android Studio , click on :

`>` **Run**
`>` **Flutter Run 'main.dart' in Release Mode**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I always prefer to learn **shortcuts**

You can use the following Shortcuts to open the configuration of the run and write **--release**

<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> then Press <kbd>0</kbd> and Press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Finally, you are there where you just have to write **--release** and Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

I only change package name at /android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt as the same with applicationID at /android/app/build.gradle,
and now it's running...

Answer (score -1):

Open the launch.json file in VS Code.

If you do not have a launch.json file, go to the Run view in VS Code and click create a launch.json file.

In the configurations section, change the flutter Mode property to the build mode you want to target.
For example, if you want to run in debug mode, your launch.json might look like this:

```
 "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flutter",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "debug"
    }
   ]
```

Run the app through the Run view.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to just get rid of the debug tag from the rightmost corner of the app,
u can use the

```
this =>  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
```

into your main.dart file in the material app widget.